# No me funcionan los Helpers

Tags: mvc, razor

Cuando pulso el botón submit no responden los Helpers. Evidentemente algo falta pero no se qué es. La idea es que los Helpers hagan su evaluación y si esta todo bien, despues se enviarán los datos al Controlador.
Aca el código.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegistrarUsuario", "Usser", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "f1" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Aca la clase Usser.

```html
 public class Usser
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public String Surname { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public String Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public String UsserName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public String Pass { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public String Address { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public int AdminType { get; set; } //Tipo de admin: "1" es administrador. "2" Usuario.
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter student name.")]
        public int Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Coloca el código del modelo para ver las validaciones que tiene

Comment: Evidentemente no entendí esto de los Helpers, como el Modelo?, es decir tengo una clase Usser adentro de la carpeta Models cuyas propiedades tienen todas [Requiered].

Comment: @Claudio, el modelo se refiere a la clase que le envías al razor para que construya el html y los validadores. Esta clase suele llevar decoradores en sus propiedades

Comment: Gracias @Arriel ahí subí la clase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que la validación del lado del cliente funcione, sin hacer postback, ASP.NET MVC utiliza **jQuery**. Asegúrate que estás incluyendo las librerías adecuadas en las vistas donde lo estás utilizando. Puedes crear un bundle en el archivo **App_Start/BundleConfig.cs** con los javascripts necesarios.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval")
.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"));
```

Y debes incluir las llaves en el WebConfig

```
 <appSettings>
   ...
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
```

Luego, en tu cshtml (vista de razor), al final

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Eso debería ser suficiente para que puedas validar del lado del cliente. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @Arriel por tu respuesta! lo que yo hice fue directamente poner los <script> en el .cshtml donde tengo el formulario sin agregar nada al BundleConfig.cs y tampoco al WebConfig y me funciona también!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO! Para que funcionen los Helpers una solución fue poner estos  en el .cshtml donde tengo el formulario.

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```